# CSS to customize button?

Tags: java, css, frameworks, vaadin, vaadin7

How to I can customize the buttons of vaadin ? I'm trying to set height and width but doesn't work and I try align an image on center of button also and doesn't work.

I'm trying this.

```
/** css file styles.scss */
.myButton{
       width:60px;
       height:60px;
       border:none;
       text-align:center;
}

/** my button */
Button btnMyButton = new Button();
btnMyButton.setIcon(new ThemeResource("../icons/myicon.png"));
btnMyButton.addStyleName("myButton");
```

any idea ?

Comment: You just want to set height, width and an image? Aren't texts already centred?

Comment: I want to set height and width of button and centralize the icon(image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a button having just an icon is quite easy. If you want hover effects it's getting tricky, therefore you should use the `NativeButton`.

```
Button btnLogout = new Button();
btnLogout.setIcon(new ThemeResource("icons/logout.png"));
btnLogout.addStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK); // define it as a link button => no borders, just the icon. Every theme has this style-name.
btnLogout.setDescription("Logout"); // set hint
```

Comment: yep, I did this. There's some way to set border ? example: .v-button{border:1px solid black;} ?